# Converting images to a specific JPG quality

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I want to convert image formats to JPG in a specific quality

The following command doesn't work for some reason , all i get is NULL

`gm convert -quality 80 '/tmp/phpK31vNK' JPEG:'/tmp/phpK31vNK' && cat '/tmp/phpK31vNK'`

However the following command works fine but graphicsmagick set the default quality which is 75

`gm convert '/tmp/phpK31vNK' JPEG:'/tmp/phpK31vNK' && cat '/tmp/phpK31vNK'`

Comment: Do you actually need the output file after you `cat` it?

Comment: @Mark Setchell yes ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
gm convert image1 -quality 60 JPEG:image2
```

But if image1 is always a jpeg you can skip the `JPEG:` specification:

```
gm convert image1 -quality 60 image2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the output file after you have `cat`ed its contents, you can avoid creating it altogether as well as an unnecessary extra process to `cat` it. You just tell **GraphicsMagick** to create a JPEG and send it straight to `stdout` like this:

```
gm convert input.jpg -quality 80 jpeg:-
```

We can see it works by changing the quality and counting the bytes output like this:

```
# Low quality => small size
gm convert test.jpg -quality 60 jpeg:- | wc -c
9036

# Higher quality => larger size
gm convert test.jpg -quality 80 jpeg:- | wc -c
11513
```